# Get Find ID connected with range of numbers by some number. Better way?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm saving ID's to object under key what representing range of numbers. ID is valid for given range:

```
let ranges = {
  "1-100": 102,
  "101-698": 47,
  "699-748": 999,
  ...
}
```

As input I give you number and I need ID (`Example: num 50 = ID 102, num 500 = ID 47`). Doing this by:

```
let keys = Object.keys(ranges);
let ID;
for (let i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
    let range = keys[i].split("-");
    if (winningTicket >= range[0] && winningTicket <= range[1]) {
        ID = ranges[keys[i]];
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there better way? I think this is very dumb algorithm and saving mechanism...

Comment: This is not a dumb solution, You can use this. There are no issues. The `break` has covered all the issues of unnecessary comparisons, Using `break` your solution will work great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of getting `Object.keys` and iterating through it, simply use `for..in` loop

```js
let d = document.querySelector('div');
let ob = {
  '0-200': 10,
  '201-400': 20,
  '401-600': 30
};

function getId(num) {
  let key = '';
  for (key in ob) {
    let range = key.split('-').map((v) => +v);
    if (num >= range[0] && num <= range[1]) {
      return ob[key]; // Return statement will automatically break the loop
    }
  }
}

d.innerHTML = 'Num=300:ID=' + getId(300) + '<br>' + 'Num=500:ID=' + getId(500);
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will use this on other places where I using this type of searching in object. But it is not really answer for my question. Already answered well (i think) by @doodlemeister

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and check the keys of the object are in the wanted range.

```js
var ranges = { "1-100": 102, "101-698": 47, "699-748": 999 },
    value = 50,
    key = Object.keys(ranges).find(k => {
        var [left, right] = k.split('-').map(Number);
        return left <= value && value <= right;
    });
  
console.log(ranges[key]);
```